# JSF Validator: ValidateDoubleRange passed a Double Object and it is think i am always out of range. Why?

Tags: jsf, icefaces, validation

```
I have an inputtext, nothing fancy in it:

                <ice:inputText value="Test" rendered="#{!element.flag}"
                               partialSubmit="true" >
                    <f:validateDoubleRange minimum="#{element.minimumValueNum}"
                                           maximum="#{element.maximumValueNum}"/>
                </ice:inputText>
```

element.minimumValue is a Double Object, the same is true for element.minimumValue, the problem is that the validator always thinks that I am out of range (with any given value)...

If i give concrete values:

```
            <ice:inputText value="Test" rendered="#{!element.flag}"
                           partialSubmit="true" >
                <f:validateDoubleRange minimum="10"
                                       maximum="100"/>
            </ice:inputText>
```

It works like a charm:

If i use a string conversion, it is also OK:

```
                <ice:inputText value="Test" rendered="#{!element.flag}"
                               partialSubmit="true" >
                    <f:validateDoubleRange minimum="#{element.maximumValueNumString}"
                                           maximum="#{element.maximumValueNumString}"/>
                </ice:inputText>
```

At the proper Bean:

```
... public String getMaximumValueNumString() {
     return maximumValueNum.toString();
 }
 public String getMinimumValueNumString() {
    return minimumValueNum.toString();
}...
```

So i need to make a conclusion that i cannot pass a Double object to the doubleRangeValidator, is it TRUE?

Comment: how are `maximumValueNum` and `minimumValueNum` being initialized and what is the scope of your bean?

Answer (score 2):

I think you should really double check your 'element' mapping or annotations, maybe it's giving you null, and the range it's always ZERO.

My Own Simple Example:

```
    <ice:inputText value="#{transfer.monto}" partialSubmit="true" id="monto">
      <f:validateDoubleRange minimum="#{transfer.minimum}" maximum="#{transfer.maximum}"/>
    </ice:inputText>
```

Values:

```
public double getMinimum() {
    return 10d;
}

public double getMaximum() {
    return 100d;
}
```

Result when using "5":

Validation Error: The attribute ......: 10 and 100.

..

So, short answer, it supports the dynamic values.

Regards.